# AutoCompleteTextView repeats other Controls under each Item in Dropdown

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I've got a fragment with an AutoCompleteTextView and EditText-Field

It looks like that:
[Start activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsjWG.png)

When I start typing for the autocomplete-function it suddenly replicates the EditText under each entry:

[How AutoCompleteTextView  behaves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTyAW.png)

What am I doing wrong? I also tried different Layouts or no separate layout for the AutoCompleteTextView, but it behaves like this, no matter what i do.

Here is my layout:

...

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/window_background"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/recipientName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:completionThreshold="0"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20sp"
        android:background="@color/Plum"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:autofillHints="test"
        android:lines="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"           />
</LinearLayout>
```

...

Comment: java code??????

Comment: Yes, you're so right! I thougt I'd be a layout problem, but I found that I referred the whole fragment's layout. for the Array-Adapter - I think this already solves the problem. Thank you for the notice!!!